# Google Apps Script - Custom Triggers - Just Month + Day - No Year

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

In short, I have code that I would like to trigger on the first day of a *specific* month. So, for example, I want to run X-script on Jan 1, but not Feb 1st, March 1st etc. Based on my testing, it seems the atDate function requires the year variable and I'd like the trigger to fire every year on Jan 1, rather than just x year.

This is the version of the timed trigger function I've been working with.

```
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("moveNumbersDecember")
  .timeBased()
  .atDate(xxxx, 1, 1)
  .create();
}
```

Is there any other function I could use, or workaround for atDate()? My other attempts have been with making the A1 cell on a sheet a clock using today(), then trying to make an if function where if A1 = January 1, then run X script. But I'm very new to coding and haven't been able to make it work.

Any ideas/help extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

GAS do not have yearly trigger, but try this workaround. Create a trigger that runs every month. This runs every month BUT only call the function you want to do if January 1 comes via checking the month of current date.

```
function createMonthlyTrigger() {
  // every month, the trigger created will run checkIfJan1()
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("checkIfJan1")
           .timeBased()
           .onMonthDay(1)
           .atHour(0)
           .create();
}

function checkIfJan1() {
  var date = new Date();
  // if jan 1, then run moveNumbersDecember()
  if (date.getMonth() === 0) {
    moveNumbersDecember();
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, really clear and excellent post!  I understand everything you did.  My issue is that I don't know where to position these trigger functions in relation to where I've defined my moveNumbersDecemeber() function.  I made a new sheet to experiment with and here's what I've been trying to make work. [link](https://imgur.com/a/dm5eD9P)   I've essentially moved the moveNumbersJuly() function around and haven't been able to make it behave. Any insight is greatly appriciated!

Comment: I'm not sure of the behavior when `atHour` is not included. Can you include it and make sure it will coincide with the time during your testing? What was the issue? Did your trigger fire successfully? was `moveNumbersJuly` not called? or it was executed but did nothing? Check under your executions tab and debug. First look, i'm not seeing anything off with your script. It is still unclear to me and you can clarify it once you answer my questions here.